# "No data received" on GET request

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting a "No data received" error, I know this is common with Google Chrome so I tried in IE and I get a connection problem error. Here is my script, I really don't see what is causing this error.

```
$getAlName = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=" . $cat);
$alName = mysql_feth_assoc($getAlName);

$images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE category=" . $alName['name']);
while($imgs = mysql_fetch_object($images)) {
    $url = $imgs->url; 
    $id = $imgs->id;
    echo ("<img src='" . $url . "'></img>\n"); 

}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with direct php mysql queries in ages, but mysql_feth_assoc should probably be mysql_fetch_assoc for a start

Comment: Never ever do basic testing on queries without a `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` type construct. This would show you the syntax error your second query has.

Comment: I had 'or die' in it at one point but I was still getting the error so I removed it.

Comment: @faceman: That makes no sense. Why would you remove something useful just because keeping it doesn't fix one specific issue? (And thus making hundreds of other potential bugs near-impossible to diagnose?)

Comment: Because I didn't want to add to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around your strings:

```
"SELECT * FROM images WHERE category = '" . $alName['name']) . "'";
```

...and you also got a typo, use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_feth_assoc($getAlName);`

Answer (score 1):

```
//Make a subquery and you'll thank yourself later: 
$q = "SELECT URL, ID FROM images WHERE category IN ".
  "( SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id=" . $cat . ")";

echo $q; // just to test. no data received probably has to do with no output to 
         // the browser. This will output to the browser.

$images = mysql_query($q);
// this is the same.
while($imgs = mysql_fetch_object($images)) {
    $url = $imgs->url; 
    $id = $imgs->id;
    echo ("<img src='" . $url . "'></img>\n"); 
}
```

Comment: I tried that, the No Data Received error always happened even with the HTML and/or any data getting echo'd.

Comment: What if you get rid of the loop?